# HTML: How to make a conditional message disappear when the condition is not held anymore?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to HTML. I have a condition in my .js file:

```
if (amounte < funding_amount) {
   document.getElementById("founding_alert").innerHTML = "You must 
fully fund the project!";
 }

else{// do something}
```

and my HTML I have put:

```
<div style="padding-left:40px;color:red"  id="founding_alert"> </div>
```

The problem is that, when the condition is not held, the message appears which is good, but next time (without reloading the page), when the condition is not held, the message does NOT disappear and still there.

**Question**: Why does this problem occur and how to solve it?

Comment: Reset it with `document.getElementById("founding_alert").innerHTML = ""` ?

Comment: when are you firing this script? on button click or on key press???

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes, thanks for the hint. Shall I remove the question?

Comment: Remove the queston? Of course not, why?

Comment: @JeremyThille I thought it's very simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As Jeremy Thille suggested:

```
if (amounte < funding_amount) {
       document.getElementById("founding_alert").innerHTML = "You must 
    fully fund the project!";
}
else{ 
    document.getElementById("founding_alert").innerHTML ="";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reset it in the else clause, and it's better to store it in a variable if you're using it a lot :

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("founding_alert");
if (amounte < funding_amount) {
   myDiv.innerHTML = "You must fully fund the project!";
 }

else{
   myDiv.innerHTML = "";
}
```